# Spring JPA Many To Many Relationship Slow Loading

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two models - Product and Category. There is a relation between them - m:n. How I defined the relation at the Product side:

```
@JoinTable(
        name = "products_categories",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "product_id",
                referencedColumnName = "id"
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "category_id",
                referencedColumnName = "id"
        )
)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Category> categories;
```

When I try to load only one record (`findById`) it sends only one SQL Query and it's what I want to achieve. But when I request to load more than one it sends different SQL Query for every single product. How can I fix that problem? Should I write my own SQL Query (using EntityManager)?

Comment: Can you post the code you use to _load more than one_?

Comment: @Rafa I am using the repository method findAll: `Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);`

Answer (score 0):

Using `EntityManager` you can use `LEFT JOIN FETCH` to overcome the *SELECT N+1* issue.

```
@Autowired EntityManager entityManager;

@Test
public void findWithEntityManager() {
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM ProductEntity p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.categories");
    List<ProductEntity> prods = q.getResultList();
    prods.forEach(p -> { 
        System.out.println(p.getCategories().size());
    });
}
//Hibernate: select productent0_.id as id1_4_0_, ... from product productent0_ left outer join product_category categories1_ on productent0_.id=categories1_.ProductEntity_id left outer join category categoryen2_ on categories1_.categories_id=categoryen2_.id
```

**===EDIT===**

Strangely enough, using the same query with `@Query` returning `Page<T>` results in exception:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM ProductEntity p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.categories c")
Page<ProductEntity> findAllLeftJoin(Pageable pageable);
// Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list ...
```

However using a `List<T>` it works fine but then I need to handle pagination manually.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM ProductEntity p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.categories c")    
List<ProductEntity> findAllLeftJoin();
// Hibernate: productent0_.id as id1_4_0_,... from product productent0_ left outer join product_category categories1_ on productent0_.id=categories1_.ProductEntity_id left outer join category categoryen2_ on categories1_.categories_id=categoryen2_.id
```